# Increment page number using .format() method

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using a for loop to increment the page count in `range(1-5)` by concatenating the url with the `.format()` method.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for i in range(1,5):
    URL = 'https://www.artsy.net/artists/artists-starting-with-a?page='.format(i)
    print(URL)
```

The code outputs the URL without concatenating `i` from the for loop.

**Wrong output**

`https://www.artsy.net/artists/artists-starting-with-a?page=`

`https://www.artsy.net/artists/artists-starting-with-a?page=`

`https://www.artsy.net/artists/artists-starting-with-a?page=`

`https://www.artsy.net/artists/artists-starting-with-a?page=`

Comment: Change to `'https://www.artsy.net/artists/artists-starting-with-a?page={}'.format(i)`

Answer (score 0):

U must put `{}` in the url to replace it with `i`

```
for i in range(1,5):
    URL = 'https://www.artsy.net/artists/artists-starting-with-a?page={}'.format(i)
    print(URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for i in range(1,5):
    URL = f'https://www.artsy.net/artists/artists-starting-with-a?page={i}'
    print(URL)
```

Can you try this and mark my answer right if successful.